# Store files in database as base64 encoded string

Tags: python, django, django-models

I use following model to store files in database in django app:

```
class Data(BaseModel):
    _data = models.TextField(
            db_column='data',
            blank=True)

    def set_data(self, data):
        self._data = base64.encodestring(data)

    def get_data(self):
        return base64.decodestring(self._data)
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item)
    data = property(get_data, set_data)
```

I can save such objects easly without any issue :

```
form = ItemForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    try:
        file = request.FILES['file']
    except MultiValueDictKeyError:
        errors = form._errors.setdefault(forms.forms.NON_FIELD_ERRORS, forms.util.ErrorList())
        errors.append("select file")
    else:
        item = form.save()
        item.filename = file.name
        item.save()

        blob = Data(item=item)
        blob.data = file.read()
        blob.save()
```

However, I am not able to read such encoded data. I tried to save such file to filesystem with:

```
        #save test
        new_filename = 'new_%s'%(item.filename,)
        a = open(new_filename,'w')
        a.write(blob.data)
        a.close()
```

(I used an image as test file, when ran above code, I cannot open such image, its incorrect).
What did I wrong?

Comment: Use `with` when working with files in Python

Comment: "However, I am not able to read such encoded data." Explain further.

Comment: When I tried to save such data into file with same name as original, data was incorrent (corrupted image for example).

Comment: I checked what data is saved when I do a.write(blob.data) and it contains some inproperly decoded base64. Have no idea why